# restore a db after bad backup

Tags: database, hosting, backup

i haven't got any experience in wordpress so please sorry me if answers seems too trivial.

one upon a time i had a blog. then the hosting service expired and i get a backup in a hurry way: the bad way.

- i copied all the root directory
- i dumped the mysql database

now i've just paid for reactivate the host and i want to restore the blog project (**BUT** the directory is changed now, the file are no more in */htdocs/public/www* but in */public/www/blog* ), but i am experiencing some troubles.

1. first of all i've fixed wp-config.php with the new database name, and new user, it seems to be OK.
2. then i've done a copy of all files back in the server and redone a wordpress installations via wp-admin/install.php . updated wordpress and plugins.
3. imported the database back with phpmyadmin.

now if i go to visit index.php i get this error after the title:

```
Error 404 - Not Found

Apologies, but we were unable to find what you were looking for. Perhaps searching will help.
```

and no css is loaded. i've tried the queries founded in [this link](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-move-wordpress-blog-to-new-domain-or-location/) but they have produced no changes in sql tables.

some advice?

Comment: It sounds like you most likely didn't restore the file structure properly. Inside the www directory you should upload a fresh WordPress install (as in: download the latest copy from wordpress.org, unzip it and upload the contents to the previously stated location).

After you do that, update the NEW wp-config.php file to the right database credentials. Let us know what happens after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not moving to a different domain name, the file path shouldn't really matter.

**Try these first:**

1. Made a copy of your original backup bd
2. Open the new copy and search/replace example.com/ to example.com/blog/

This should get you going no matter what server setup you have.

**If it doesn't**, and you already have a fresh install on the right place, open that copy file on a good pure-text editor (not MS Word) and remove the part that starts with:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `wp_options`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `wp_options`;
```

up until the last line before the next table, probably:

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `wp_postmeta`
--
```

Do the same for the tables `wp_users` and `wp_usermeta`.

Save yet another copy of the file and upload the new one. You should get all of your posts/comments/links/etc back inside the fresh install. You can then install any themes and plugins from scratch and pick up where you left of.

Comment: the first try was succesfull. just one more level: i've done string substitution with TextEdit, can you give me a regex for that?

Comment: I never really use regex for that step. Since it is replacing hardcoded base URLs, string replacement should do just fine, unless your URL has port numbers or anything usual.

Comment: What's your current status? You have posts and comments but not categories and tags? Categories and Tags are there, but not linked to posts?

Comment: if i go yo url.com/blog i see the last post. in that page, if i click on a tag, on a category or on a archive i am reminded to a 404 page

Comment: right. When you click the links, is the URL correct (according to your permalink settings)? Are you using one of the default themes?

Comment: i have changed permalink setting and now it works. thanks to point me till here! : )